# Does usage of a pointer cancel the "register" property of the associated variable?

Tags: c, optimization, assembly

In C, does usage of a pointer cancel the "register" property of the associated variable?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    register int clk=0;    //maybe register maybe not
    int *adr=&clk;         //not a register now? i have its address
    *adr=1;  //if i use this 1000000 times, does it exist in L1 at least?
    printf("%d",clk);
    return 0;

}
```

Gives compiler error "can't take address of register variable" but it is not register %100. it is only a chance.

Is this the slowest loop?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *p;
    int i=0;
    p=&i;
for(*p=0;(*p)<100;(*p)++)
{
    //do nothing
}
    printf("%d ",i);
    return 0;

}
```

If I make nearly all variables pointer-style and only three variables only primitive type with "register" keyword, does compiler make those three variables "really register" with a higher chance?

OK. Problem solved. I learned some assembly and found out that this depends on optimization level and also variable's volatility. Using __asm{} makes sure it computes in a register.
Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In C it's illegal to apply `&` to a variable declared with the `register` specifier.

> 6.7.1
>
> The implementation may treat any register declaration simply as an
>   auto declaration.  However, whether or not addressable storage is
>   actually used, the address of any part of an object declared with
>   storage-class  speciﬁer register cannot  be  computed,  either 
>   explicitly  (**by  use  of  the  unary & operator** as discussed in
>   6.5.3.2) or implicitly (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in
>   6.3.2.1).

And 6.5.3.2:

> The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function
>   designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that
>   designates an object that is not a bit-ﬁeld and **is not declared with
>   the register storage-class speciﬁer**.

As for C++, if you use & with a `register`, it cancels its meaning:

> ANSI C does not allow for taking the address of a register object;
>   this restriction does not apply to C++. However, if the address-of
>   operator (&) is used on an object, **the compiler must put the object in
>   a location for which an address can be represented**. In practice, this
>   means in memory instead of in a register.

Comment: Is it actually illegal? Isn’t `register` just a hint that can (actually, probably *will*) be ignored anyway?

Comment: It IS illegal in ANSI C (C99). In c++ it is legal

Comment: what if i cancel the register keyword, does usage of pointer cancel any "chance of" being register?

Comment: @friendzis I hadn't noticed the `C++` tag.

Comment: `whether or not addressable storage is actually used`. Read again.

Comment: Note that the first paragraph is a footnote and footnotes are not normative, your second paragraph is the important one.

Comment: @ouah That's right, it's more informative but the second one is more important.

Comment: There are architectures on which registers have addresses, and you can take a pointer to a register. On such architectures, a C++ compiler could in principle place the object in a register even once its address is taken. However (1) it would have to ensure that the register wasn't saved and restored across some function call, since the pointer would need to be valid throughout the life of the variable, and (b) AFAIK this happens on tiny little 8- and 16-bit microcontrollers, that you probably aren't using C++ on all that much anyway. So I agree that in practice the possibility can be ignored.

Comment: @cnicutar: You do not attribute the passage you present for C++, and it does not appear to be part of the standard. Using the address-of operator on an object does not **require** the compiler to put the object in a location for which an address can be represented. As with much of the standard, the compiler is only required to produce a program that behaves “as if” the object had an address. When an optimizer can deduce the address is not actually needed, e.g., when it is not returned to the caller and is used simply inside the local routine, the compiler need not put the object in memory.

Comment: I compiled the first sample code in the question with a recent version of clang, with -O3 for x86_64, and viewed the generated assembly code. The assembly code moved the immediate value 1 to a register and called printf; the 1 was not stored in memory prior to calling printf.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil. but i need to know if register is really used for lop. //do nothing will be replaced with a clock() or random(). can you try for me? thanks

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: You cannot know whether a register will be used, because the compiler is permitted to use a register, and the compiler is permitted not to use a register. Therefore, whether a register is used or not cannot be deduced from the C++ standard. Whether a register is used or not will depend upon the specific compiler used (and may change from version to version), the switches used with it (optimization level, machine target, and more), and the specific code that is compiled. So the answer is you **cannot** control this with C++. If you want control, you should write in assembly.

Answer (score 1):

you are right, if you use & to a register variable, that make this variable to main memory, so you can get it's address. because register variable have not address.

Comment: if i make nearly all variables pointer-style and only 3 variables only primitive type with "register" keyword, does compiler make those 3 variables "really register" with a higher chance?

Comment: The `register` keyword doesn't help the code a bit, so just skip it. The compiler will figure this out anyway. And BTW, on some hardware the registers do have a memory address.